Why does initializing a std::string with a std::string::size_type parameter and a char raise a warning?
I tried to compile the following C++ code (adapted from A. Koenig, B. E. Moo, Accelerated C++):
std::string::size_type max_len = width(foo);
std::string border{max_len, '*'};

where width is a function that returns a std::string::size_type.
The compiler raises the following warning message
narrowing conversion of ‘max_len’ from ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} to ‘char’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
   std::string border{max_len, '*'};

but I don't get why.
I have checked the documentation online and I found out that the signature of the constructor I want to use is
basic_string( size_type count, CharT ch,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );

as I was expecting.
What confuses even more is that the following snippet compiles
std::string border{std::string::size_type{10}, '*'};

I don't understand in what sense in the previous example I could have been narrowing a value of type std::string::size_type to a char.

Selecting constructor basic_string( std::initializer_list<CharT> ilist, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );...

With braces initializer list is preferred over other constructors if conversion can be done. Use parenthesis and proper constructor is selected.

Using () instead of {} works: std::string border(max_len, '*');.

Try using () instead of {}.  The example from the book that you posted uses ().

std::string border{std::string_size_type{10}, '*'}; is "\10*"s and not "**********".

I purposely used the curly braces, I know that with the () it works. I don't just want to make the snipped compile, I want to understand why it doesn't in the particular case I am telling the compiler to stop and warn me in presence on any potentially unwanted narrowing.

The why is explained in so many dupes. When you use {} for objects that have a std::initializer_list constructor, that constructor will always have precedence. So the solution, as has been said, is to use () for construction unless you explicitly want an initializer list.

Must watch CppCon 2018: Nicolai Josuttis “The Nightmare of Initialization in C++”: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs

This question is similar to: What does initializer_list do?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Ok, thank you all, all of this actually constitutes an answer :) @sweenish Before asking this question I would have never thought about the std::initializer_list ctor because I didn't know such a thing existed. I think what I fell in is a common trap for people (re)starting with C++, but I don't know how I could make my question less specific and more helpful to others. You can propose to close it if you think it's appropriate.

List-initialization - Look under "List-initializing std::initializer_list": "If a narrowing conversion is required to initialize any of the elements, the program is ill-formed."

It is enough for the values to be convertible to the value_type for the initializer_list to win. Then, apparently, some conversions are considered ill-formed, but still win. Crazy!

I think what I fell in is a common trap for people (re)starting with C++... They made a dramatization of what it is like programming in C++ into a movie, called Cube (1997).  There are plenty of common traps for the unwary.
